# New to jquery, need help in adding left position

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm new to using jquery and need help. I'm using the scrolltofixed.js and need help in adding the left: %%px. This is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#socialbar').scrollToFixed( {marginTop: $('.header').outerHeight(true) + 7,});
    $('#socialbar').bind('fixed', function() {   });
    $('#socialbar').bind('unfixed', function() {  });

    $('#sidebar').scrollToFixed({
        marginTop: $('.header').outerHeight(true) + 15,
        fixed: function() {  },
    });
});
```

This is what happends to #socialbar element when users start to scroll down the page:

```
z-index: 1000; width: 58px; position: fixed; top: 7px; left: 70px;
```

Thanks for the help,
Gregory S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method:

```
$('#socialbar').css('left', 'your value');
```

Comment: Did not work. Also the above code: 'z-index: 1000; width: 58px; position: fixed; top: 7px; left: 70px;' is an element that overrides css stylesheet, if it helps.

Comment: One more item, this appears underneath the block that scolls: '<div style="float: left; height: 20px; display: none; width: 58px;"></div>'